# how to store Image profile(jpg file) and PDF documents in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am migrating my Spring MVC services to the AWS API Gateway using Python Lambda with Dynamo Db , I have endpoint where i can store or retrieve the people image and also the reports which is PDF file , can you please suggest me which is the best practice to store the images and pdf files in AWS .

Your help is really appreciated!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind, DynamoDB has a 400KB limit on each item.

I would recommend using S3 for images and PDF documents. It also allows you to set up a CDN much more easily, rather than using something like DynamoDB.

You can always link your S3 link to an item in DynamoDB if you need to store data related to the file.

Comment: Thanks Abhaya Chauhan!!

Answer (score 1):

AWS DynamoDB has a [limit on the row size to be max of 400KB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-items). So, it is not advisable to store the binary content of image/PDF document in a column directly. Instead, you should store the image/PDF in S3 and have the link stored in a column in DynamoDB.

If you were using Java, you could have leveraged the [S3Link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-s3link-with-amazon-dynamodb/) abstraction that takes care of storing the content in S3 and maintaining the link in DynamoDB column.

Answer (score 0):

## How to do it?

I found this post quit interesting: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrate-an-application-from-using-gridfs-to-using-amazon-s3-and-amazon-documentdb-with-mongodb-compatibility/

## All in all it says:

Remember these facts before going for saving files in database:

1. A database isn’t the architecturally best choice for storing large objects.
2. File system APIs are relatively basic (such as list, get, put, and delete), a fully-featured database management system, with its complex query operators, is overkill for this use case
3. Large objects compete for resources in an OLTP system, which can negatively impact query workloads
4. Purpose-built file systems are often far more cost-effective for this use case than using a database, in terms of storage costs as well as computing costs to support the file system.

## [But what about saving it in something like MongoDB?](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/storing-large-objects-and-files/)

1. "Unlike a file system, the database will have no problem dealing with millions of objects.", Not true about Amazon S3. right!
2. "We get the power of the database when dealing with this data: we can do advanced queries to find a file, using indexes", Do we need it and what kind of query do you want to execute again `GridFS`?
3. "replication of the entire file set.", We can achieve better results with S3
4. "This has the added advantage of letting us efficiently retrieve a specific range of the given file.", [I am sure have more control over it with something like this.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/tutorial-s3-cloudfront-route53-video-streaming.html)

## Conclusion:

Do not use wrong tool for the job.